# Grafana query for distinct labels number

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have Prometheus counter `input_requests` for requests with label `ticker`:

```
{ticker: TSLA},
{ticker: AAPL},
{ticker: TSLA},
{ticker: META},
```

I want to do the chart with unique labels number in each period of time, for example 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count(changes(input_requests[1m]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query should return the number of unique values for the label `ticker` over the last minute:

```
count(
  count(last_over_time(input_requests[1m])) by (ticker)
)
```

This query works in the following way:

1. The inner `last_over_time(input_requests[1m])` returns the last value per each time series with `input_requests` name over the last minute. See [last_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time).
2. Then the inner `count(...) by (ticker)` returns the number of unique time series from the step 1 grouped per each unique `ticker` value. See [count() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count).
3. Then the outer `count()` returns the number of series returned from the step 2. This is actually the number of unique `ticker` values seen during the last minute.

Please note that the query above is calculated **independently** per each point on the graph if the query used in Grafana, e.g. it returns the number of unique `ticker` values during the last minute ending at every point on the graph. If you want obtaining a graph with per-minute step, then the following options exist:

1. Set the `min step` in the graph settings to `1m` (e.g. one minute).
2. To use [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) in the following way:

```
last_over_time(
  count(
    count(last_over_time(input_requests[1m] offset -1m)) by (ticker)
  )[1m:1m]
)
```

It converts the original query to a subquery, which is calculated with 1 minute step, and then the outer `last_over_time(...[1m:1m])` returns a graph with 1-minute steps. The query adds negative [offset](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) in order to show the number of `ticker` values seen per the given minute. If the `offset` isn't set, then the query would show the number of `ticker` values for the previous minute per each 1-minute step on the graph.